# How to subscribe to a password-protected feed with Outlook?

Tags: login, rss, account-password

When I open a password-protected joomla-site in Firefox, after login I can see its RSS-feed. But when I try to subscribe to that feed via Outlook, it opens a "failed to open website" window instead, failing to add the feed, and there seems to be no way to tell Outlook how to login. Is there any way to configure either Outlook or Joomla (e.g. via a `?username=...` switch in the the RSS-URL) such that the RSS can be subscribed to while remaining protected?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14047546/321973

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would try following syntax for RSS URL in Outlook:
`http://<username>:<password>@<full rss url>`

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't seem to work (maybe because the username contains a space, so I tried quoting `"` and escaping the space as `%20` as well to no avail)

Comment: Username with a space!?! I must be from another galaxy... Sorry...

Comment: I had no saying in this, I'm afraid...

Comment: Haven't thought so, trust me...

Comment: Did you btw try this on a password-protected RSS feed (with sensible usernames)? I don't use any other Joomla-accounts, so I can't check whether it's just that specific site or the method is actually different

Comment: [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14047546/321973) asks for this as a feature, but lacking response from OP to the only answer there makes it impossible to determine whether they got it working...

Comment: Sorry to inform you, it doesn't work! I have tested on one of my test sites, and it doesn't work. Dunno what else to suggest.